# bash variable scope issue with function fork (&)

Tags: bash, variables, scope, fork

I want to run functions `f1` and `f2` simultaneously and then perform an action only when they are both done.
It seems that if the functions are backgrounded as in the script, the `f1/f2done` value changes are not seen by the script, the until loop does not terminate and the final line is not executed.

1. How should this be implemented?

***Edit - additional functionality required***
2. Is there a way I could read/write to main process variables in the script (without using files)?

Thank you for reading.

```
#!/bin/bash

f1done="false"
f2done="false"

function f1 {
    echo "f1: "
    sleep 4
    echo "f1 done."
    f1done="true"
}

function f2 {
    echo "f2: "
    sleep 2
    echo "f2 done."
    f2done="true"
}

f1 &
f2 &

until [[ "$f1done" == "true" && "$f2done" == "true" ]]; do
    echo "$f1done $f2done...";
    sleep 3;
done

echo "Both done."
```

Comment: Things run in the background are in separate processes; changes in them cannot affect the parent process.

Comment: You are looking for multi-threading and bash does not support that.  There was some talk of korn shell (ksh) supporting multithreading (http://kornshell.com/doc/faq.html Q7) but I don't think it happened.  Other than that, I'm not aware of any shell that multi-threads, you need something like C, C++, or Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`f1` and `f2` will be separate processes thus having separate address space from the main process. Therefore your loop will be infinite.

You need to use `wait` instead.

i.e.

change

```
until [[ "$f1done" == "true" && "$f2done" == "true" ]]; do
    echo "$f1done $f2done...";
     sleep 3;
done
```

to

```
wait;
wait;
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, the wait statement works nicely. Please see my question for an additional requirement.

Comment: The second `wait` is unnecessary; `wait` with no arguments doesn't complete until *all* background processes have finished.